# "Except of" vs. "except for" vs. "apart from"

Tags: idioms

I've used to say "**except of**" for a lot of sentences but recently someone noted (or corrected) me "**apart from**". I don't really remember the context that this correction was in. Anyway, after sometime I saw [this article in Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/apart-from-or-except-for) which is talking about the difference between "except for" to "apart from". That says that my habbit to say "except **of**" is a mistake?

Comment: Yes, I don't think I've ever heard of "except of", but I have heard of "except for".

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake. And please note: I used to say, not: I've used to say. except of is not grammatical. correct usage for have used: "I've used a stove, but I am not a good cook."

Comment: It's possibly also worth noting that most places where you can say "except for," you could also just say "except." For example, "all flowers, except for roses" is pretty much the same as "all flowers, except roses." There are a few cases where "except for" means something different (for example, "I **would** hate all flowers, except for roses" means something slightly different from "I hate all flowers, except roses" and you couldn't leave "for" out of the first one). But mostly, you won't go wrong if you just delete the preposition altogether.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, 'except of' is wrong. This error may be caused by confusion with *with the exception **of***, as in *With the exception of Jim, everyone must report for work at 8am.*

As with the example above, sometimes these confusions arise because different forms of a word use different prepositions, or one form has a preposition while the other doesn't (e.g. *discuss the problem* (no preposition), *have a discussion **about** the problem*).